# What is the Keras 2.0 equivalent of `similarity = keras.layers.merge([target, context], mode='cos', dot_axes=0)`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Keras 2.0 has removed `keras.layers.merge` and now we should use `keras.layers.Concatenate`,

I was wonder what is the equivalent to having the 'cos' and 'dot_axis=0' arg, for example

`similarity = keras.layers.merge([target, context], mode='cos', dot_axes=0)`

How would I write that in keras 2.0?

Comment: What does the `mode='cos'` do?

Comment: it's supposed to make it a cos similarity function https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/1.2.2/layers/core/#merge

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52021481/2099607). You can use `Dot` layer with `normalize` argument set to `True`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Computing cosine similarity between two tensors in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003027/computing-cosine-similarity-between-two-tensors-in-keras)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried with:

similarity = dot([target, context], axes=1, normalize=True)

Comment: Changes to your question should not go into an answer. Rather, edit your question directly. Answers are strictly for answering.

Answer (score 0):

How Can i convert below old from `version 1+ code` to new `keras version 2.3.0`.
you provided above solution but if i need to use **outputshape** the how can i do this.

```
from keras.layers import merge

merge(inputs=[question_enc_1, answer_enc_1], mode=similarity, output_shape=lambda _: (None, 1))
```

till i now i converted above to

```
from keras import backend as K

K.dot([question_pool, answer_pool], output_shape=lambda _: (None, 1))
```

[Click To see Screenshot of code line that shows unexpected arguments are there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SekJY.png)
i think here it doesn't accept output shape param.

Comment: please don't ask question in an answer. use a different question for your question. you can add a link to this question